# MySQL 'innodb_file_format' variable doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, owncloud, nextcloud

I am currently setting up a Nextcloud server and have everything set up and working, except MySQL 4-byte character support. I am using the default package host for Ubuntu Server 20.04.1 LTS and the MySQL package from said host. It says that it's version is: 'Server version: 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4 (Ubuntu)'

Nextcloud's Security & Setup Warnings section of the Administration page says that:

> MySQL is used as database but does not support 4-byte characters. To be able to handle 4-byte characters (like emojis) without issues in filenames or comments for example it is recommended to enable the 4-byte support in MySQL. For further details read the documentation page about this.

The problem is that when I run the command `show variables like 'innodb_file_format';` from said [documentation page](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/16/admin_manual/configuration_database/mysql_4byte_support.html), it returns this:

```
mysql> show variables like 'innodb_file_format';
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

I have tried just listing all of the variables and have posted the output on pastebin [here](https://pastebin.com/ufX5Y6VZ)

As you can see, the variable 'innodb_file_format' simply doesn't exist. Is there any way to correct this? I would very much appreciate any ideas

Comment: what about `show GLOBAL variables like "%innodb_file%";` ?

Comment: That variable was deprecated in MySQL 5.7 and removed in 8.0. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_format for explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mysql [release notes](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=7704) on v8.0 says (emphasis is mine):

> The following options will be removed:
>
> **innodb_file_format**
>
> innodb_file_format_check
>
> innodb_file_format_max
>
> innodb_large_prefix

So, the documentation linked in the question is simply incorrect, this system variable does not exist in mysql. I do not think it affects its ability to use utf8mb4 charset.